# Tracking when an external link is clicked in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

Based on these instructions- [Javascript code to record click on link to PDF - Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013065/javascript-code-to-record-click-on-link-to-pdf-qualtrics)

I set up the link (with unique ID of human) in the question, I added the javascript to the javascript panel in the question but I am not sure what to add into the survey flow section.

This is what I have now and it doesn't seem to be working:

1=human

Thanks

Here is my link I need to track-

```html
<a href="http://vpf2.cise.ufl.edu/Classic/Interaction/Prototype/23341" id="human" target="_blank">Test Link</a>
```

and here is the javascript I put with the question.

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var a = $("human"); //adjust ID here

      a.onclick = function() {
          Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("clicked", 1); //adjust embedded data variable here
      }

});
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the original post with them.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is getting `undefined`, since the selector is searching for the tag `<human>`.

Try this: `$('#human')` to select the element by it's ID.

**[EDIT]**

And use to bind the click event:

```
    a.on('click',function() {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("clicked", 1); //adjust embedded data variable here
    });
```

Comment: That didn't work. When I go to check the results it says " 1. $('#human') .  here is a link to the survey in case that helps. The link is on the second page- https://ufl.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_892LRskwk3jgNX7

Comment: Hmm, my bad. You're using jQuery, didn't notice the `onclick`.

Comment: Still nothing, sorry. I'm looking at the help section of their site and it says something about inside or outside the function? Do I have that correctly in my code?      https://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/javascript-in-qualtrics/

Comment: Well, the code is fine. But it seems Qualtrics has some conflicts with jQuery. So they suggest to use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` to select the elements. So you add that and then use `$j('#human')` instead `$('#human')`

Comment: Add the no conflict line right above the other var line?

Comment: Before `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine`.

Comment: It still displays $j('#human'), not "Clicked", in the results section and displays that regardless of whether the link was clicked or not.  Sorry, I hope I'm not miscommunicating something.

Comment: Hi Filipe, I wanted to thank you for your help and advice! We ended up doing a different method to create a unique URL with a username attached using embedded data and the website they're clicking to can extract that username, allowing us to track. Just wanted to thank you and let you know so you didn't spend any more time on this!

Comment: Ohn, no problem. Glad to help a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In survey flow:

```
human = 0
```

Question html:

```
<a href="http://vpf2.cise.ufl.edu/Classic/Interaction/Prototype/22318?username=" id="human" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
       $('human').observe('click',function(event) {
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("human", "1"); 
       });
});
```

Note: In Qualtrics $ refers to prototypejs, not jquery.

Comment: That didn't work, but thank you for your response and time! We found a workaround that does almost what we want and we are going with that. Thanks again