# How to record the time an external link is clicked in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics, external-links

The link provided here answers how Qualtrics records if an external link is clicked or not.
[Tracking when an external link is clicked in Qualtrics with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225021/tracking-when-an-external-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics-with-javascript)

But can I know **when** or **the exact time** that the link is clicked? 
What is the Javascript I can use? Thanks!

**Update 1:**

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $('extLink').on('click', function(name, event) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked', '1');
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date(), '1');
        });
});
```

**Update 2:** 
Embedded data part:

```
clicked=0${date://CurrentDate/c}
```

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $('extLink').on('click', function(name, event) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date().toGMTString(), '1');
        });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date(), '1');`?

Comment: Did I use this code below correctly (please see the updated question)? It didn't work. I'm sorry that it's my first time using javascript in Qualtrics.

Comment: I meant that you could try to remove the old `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked', '1');` and add only the `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date(), '1');` I mentioned. If the embedded data needs to be a `string` try using `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date().toGMTString(), '1');`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: Ok, I'll make a proper answer here so your question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this piece of code here:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $('extLink').on('click', function(name, event) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date(), '1');
        });
});
```

Or this one if you want your embedded data to be of a string type

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $('extLink').on('click', function(name, event) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('clicked at ' + new Date().toGMTString(), '1');
        });
});
```