# How to record a link click and then automatically click next button in Qualtrics with javascript?

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, qualtrics

I am working on a survey in Qualtrics. In this survey, I direct respondents to a link at the end of the survey.

I want to record whether or not respondents click on the link. If they click on the link, then I would like for the survey to automatically click the next button (thereby finishing the survey).

I've tried the code in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225021/tracking-when-an-external-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics-with-javascript) on Stack Overflow and the follow-up post on Qualtrics [forum](https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/2809/track-whether-a-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics-even-a-respondent-leaves-for-the-opened-new-page), without much luck.

Currently, I've created an embedded field called `ClickLink` which is placed at the beginning of the survey and is set to zero

The HTML of the Qualtrics questions is:

```
This is a link: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="Link">Click here</a>
```

The javascript for the question's behavior follows the Qualtrics [forum](https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/2809/track-whether-a-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics-even-a-respondent-leaves-for-the-opened-new-page) and is:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    jQuery('Link').click(function(event) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("ClickLink", "1");
        jQuery("#NextButton").click();
    });
});
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in getting the survey to function as desired. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jQuery 'Link' selector is incorrect. It should have a # in front of the id:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    jQuery('#Link').click(function(event) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("ClickLink", "1");
        jQuery("#NextButton").click();
    });
});
```