# Qualtrics: Measure which button in an embedded Tweet was clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter, click, embedding, qualtrics

I would like to measure whether a participant clicks on an Embedded Tweet, and especially whether they click on the like/share/reply button.

I already figured out, how to embedd a post via [Twitter](https://publish.twitter.com/?query=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FX%2Fstatus%2F1743504138309132368&widget=Tweet), which then looks like that in the HTML View of the Text/Graphic Question

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">reminder to get up before your legs fall asleep</p>&mdash; X (@X) <a href="https://twitter.com/X/status/1743504138309132368?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">January 6, 2024</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Which then looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX1jY.png)

I also figured out how to measure whether a link was clicked ([thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225021/tracking-when-an-external-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics-with-javascript)). And got it to worked with an unrelated link.

However, when I apply it to either of the links in this embedding, it does not work. Furthermore, I do not just want to know whether someone clicks on the tweet, but especially, which of the buttons they clicked on (or whether they clicked on something else).

Do you have an Idea how I can manage that?

Best Wishes :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.