# Javascript to track how many times an audio/video file is played (in Qualtrics)

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

In a Qualtrics survey, I'm trying to capture how many times an audio or video file is played by respondents.

I'm a Javascript novice and have read previous questions about how to capture whether a respondents clicks a link ([Javascript code to record click on link to PDF - Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013065/javascript-code-to-record-click-on-link-to-pdf-qualtrics); [Tracking when an external link is clicked in Qualtrics with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225021/tracking-when-an-external-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics-with-javascript); [Tracking when an external link is clicked in Qualtrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379227/tracking-when-an-external-link-is-clicked-in-qualtrics)). However, when I try to apply a similar strategy for media files to even capture whether a media file is played (create an embedded element click1=0 that appears before the item I'm tracking, giving an ID audio1 to the tracked item, and adding the following Javascript code, it stays at the default value of 0.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var a = $("audio1");
      a.onclick = function() {
          Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("click1", 1);
      }
});
```

Is there a different strategy to track clicks for an audio or video file (rather than URL)? How can I capture how many times a file is played, rather than simply a binary variable for whether or not it is clicked?

I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you!

EDITED 1/29/18:
Using the GUI to link to a file uploaded to Qualtrics, the resulting html is:

```
<video class="qmedia" controls="true" height="260" preload="auto" 
width="320"><source src="[URL OF MEDIA CLIP]" type="video/mp4"><embed 
align="middle" autoplay="false" 
bgcolor="white" class="qmedia" controller="true" height="260" 
pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
src="[URL OF MEDIA CLIP]" 
type="video/quicktime" width="320"></video>
```

I wasn't sure where to add the ID statement and ended up trying quite a few locations, but no luck yet. And yes, I do realize this is technically a video clip, but assumed (perhaps naively) the mechanism is the same!

Comment: You can increment the a variable. Ex: `counter++;`

Comment: This is going to definitely depend on the html embed code you are using for your audio. If you can share an example of the html (feel free to anonymize it) I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the html code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
 var playCounter = 0;
 function onFinished(){
  playCounter++;
  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("click1", playCounter);
 }
 
 $('videoPlayer').addEventListener('ended', onFinished);

});
```

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" class="qmedia" controls="true" height="260" preload="auto" width="320">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <embed align="middle" autoplay="false" bgcolor="white" class="qmedia" controller="true" height="260" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
        src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/quicktime" width="320">
</video>
```

What this does is track the number of times the video finishes playing, and stores that number to the embedded data "click1".

Comment: YES, thank you so much! This is capturing whether the clip is fully played, and "onStart" is capturing whether the clip is started. You've been a tremendous help.

Comment: It's no problem! Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes!